# Can not detect my sony xperia tipo dual

Tags: sony

I have a sony xperia tipo dual phone, and when I connect it via USB and try to download an app from the market, it gets downloaded and installed on my phone, so I guess my phone is detectable by ubuntu, the problem is I cannot see it or mount its internal storage nor its SD card so I can e.g. transfer files or so, what can I do to solve this problem ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you download app to phone using browser, that are not downloaded via usb. Probably your phone is connected to internet via wi-fi/ GPRS. The app is downloaded using that connection (not usb).

Go to `Settings → Xperia → connectivity → USB  connection mode`.
Change the mode to `mass storage mode (MSC)`

Now hopefully you can see the sd card.

This answer is based on my xperia ray. So the option may be hiddedn somewhere else.

Comment: This connects the SD Card, but not the internal storage. How do I connect internal storage without having to install that connectivity software which only works on Windows?